# Changing The Location Of Titlebar In KDE Plasma

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde, manjaro, plasma

I want to change the location of the title bar in Manjaro Linux.
Normally in every os title bar is located on the top of the application window.
Is there any way to customize the location of the title bar?

Comment: I am not aware that this is possible on KDE by default. However, I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/bzqdje/how_to_move_windows_titlebar_to_left/)